# Filtering NSArray of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an array of dictionaries that was pulled from a RESTful API. I currently am trying to filter out the data as needed where the "domain" is equal to "youtube.com".

How can I filter this out? I've looked into

```
results.filter({
    $0["domain"] != "youtube.com"
```

but not sure how to go deeper to get it to work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the `data` object is the one represented by `$0`, then you'll need to start with that, `$0["data"]!["domain"] != "youtube.com"`. Are you getting an error message? What problem are you having?

Comment: @MattLong I have updated my code to show the issue.

Comment: So the debugger is explaining what's going on there. You are attempting to call `filter` on an object of type `NSArray`. You need to either use a Swift array of dictionaries (e.g. typecast to [[String:AnyObject]]) or you need to use the NSArray functions such at `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`. Also, your JSON screenshot does not seem representative of what you show in code. Where is the `children` key?

Comment: By the way, I'd discourage the use of `as!` because there are too many network/server errors that could cause this to fail (and your code would crash). You should also make sure that `data` is not `nil`, too. You want to be able to handle network errors gracefully. Also, if you're not going to use the latest version of Swift (which we can infer from your code sample), you should tell us which version of Swift and/or Xcode you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use Swift array, casting `theJSON` to `[[String: AnyObject]]` rather than `NSMutableArray`. Then, you don't have to cast `results`. And then you can use `filter`.

In Swift 1.2, that might be:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
    if error != nil || data == nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    var parseError: NSError?
    if let resultObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0), error: &parseError) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        let results = resultObject.filter() { ($0["data"]?["domain"] as? String) != "youtube.com" }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // use results here
        }
    } else {
        print(parseError)
        return
    }

}
task.resume()
```

Or, in Swift 2:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
    guard data != nil && error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    do {
        let resultObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [[String: AnyObject]]
        let results = resultObject?.filter() { ($0["data"]?["domain"] as? String) != "youtube.com" }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // use results here
        }
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}
task.resume()}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
func filteredArrayUsingPredicate(_ predicate: NSPredicate) -> [AnyObject]
```

to filter an NSArray instance.