# JSON Data Parsing in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I currently have an array that houses a bunch of different pieces of JSON. If I print out

```
my_array[3]
```

I get something like the following... I am trying to parse out pieces of this such as "domain" and other keys found inside. I've tried extracting the data, but fail to get it done correctly. Is there an easy way to go about doing this? All the data is extracted and inserted into the array at this point.

```
{
    data =     {
        "approved_by" = "<null>";
        archived = 0;
        author = Lingenfelter;
        "author_flair_css_class" = "<null>";
        "author_flair_text" = "<null>";
        "banned_by" = "<null>";
        clicked = 0;
        created = 1448739500;
        "created_utc" = 1448710700;
        distinguished = "<null>";
        domain = "youtube.com";
        downs = 0;
        edited = 0;
        from = "<null>";
        "from_id" = "<null>";
        "from_kind" = "<null>";
        gilded = 0;
        hidden = 0;
        "hide_score" = 0;
        id = 3ukrul;
        "is_self" = 0;
        likes = "<null>";
        "link_flair_css_class" = rock;
        "link_flair_text" = Rock;
        locked = 0;
        media =         {
            oembed =             {
                "author_name" = BiSHTUBE;
                "author_url" = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6UZX3ax9mq-c1P4hh7oDyQ";
                description = "Brand-new idol SHiT http://www.amazon.co.jp/Brand-new-idol-SHiT-BiSH/dp/B00UG99D6C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1430188312&amp;sr=8-1&amp;keywords=BiSH \U6b4c\U8a5e\U2193 BiSH-\U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b- \U4f5c\U8a5e BiSH\U00d7JxSxK\U00d7\U677e\U9688\U30b1\U30f3\U30bf\U3000\U4f5c\U66f2 \U677e\U9688\U30b1\U30f3\U30bf \U3042\U3042\U5acc\U3044 \U3084\U3081\U306b\U3057\U306a\U3044\Uff1f \U30cf\U30c3\U30bf\U30ea\U3070\U304b\U308a \U5e7e\U5343\U306e\U3053\U3053\U306f\U307e\U308b\U3067 \U30d1\U30e9\U30c0\U30a4\U30b9\Uff1f \U9593\U9055\U3044 \U7b97\U6570\U82e6\U624b\U306a\U5b66\U751f\U305f\U3061\U304c \U3042\U304f\U305b\U304f\U3068 \U96fb\U5353\U305f\U305f\U304f \U4e16\U754c \U30ae\U30f3\U30ae\U30f3\U306b\U62e1\U6563\U306a\U3055\U308c\U305f \U30a2\U30a4\U30c9\U30eb\U306e\U547d\U306f\U5982\U4f55\U306b\Uff1f \U884c\U304b\U306a\U304f\U3061\U3083 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U306a \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U3042\U3069\U3051\U306a\U3044\U3000\U305d\U308a\U3083\U306d \U6c7a\U5b9a\U304b\U3089\U306e \U901f\U3055\U306f\U7570\U5e38\U3060\U3057 \U8a00\U308f\U306a\U3044\U3067 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U3060 \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U88cf\U8fd4\U3057\U3067\U3082 \U306a\U3093\U3067\U3082\U3044\U3044\U3088 \U3059\U3050\U6b32\U3057\U304c\U308a\U3060\U306d \U884c\U3063\U3061\U3083\U3046\U306e\Uff1f \U554f\U984c \U3042\U3063\U3051\U3089\U304b\U3093\U306b \U898b\U3048\U3066\U308b\U306a\U3089\U3070 \U4e71\U5fc3\U3067 \U3072\U3063\U304d\U308a\U306a\U3057\U306b \U523b\U307f\U305f\U3044 \U6b63\U89e3 \U5618\U3064\U304d\U3060\U3089\U3051\U554f\U984c\U3042\U308a\U306e \U30ad\U30c4\U30cd\U3061\U3083\U3093\U305f\U3061\U3082 \U3053\U3053\U306b\U6765\U308c\U3070 \U30d1\U30e9\U30c0\U30a4\U30b9\Uff01 \U30ae\U30f3\U30ae\U30f3\U597d\U5947\U5fc3\U306e\U76ee\U305f\U3061 \U30a2\U30a4\U30c9\U30eb\U306e\U547d\U306f\U5982\U4f55\U306b\Uff1f \U884c\U304b\U306a\U304f\U3061\U3083 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U306a \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U3042\U3069\U3051\U306a\U3044\U3000\U305d\U308a\U3083\U306d \U6c7a\U5b9a\U304b\U3089\U306e \U901f\U3055\U306f\U7570\U5e38\U3060\U3057 \U8a00\U308f\U306a\U3044\U3067 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U3060 \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U88cf\U8fd4\U3057\U3067\U3082 \U306a\U3093\U3067\U3082\U3044\U3044\U3088 \U3059\U3050\U6b32\U3057\U304c\U308a\U3060\U306d \U884c\U3063\U3061\U3083\U3046\U306e\Uff1f \U8ab0\U3067\U3082 \U308f\U3051\U3044\U304b\U305a \U305d\U3093\U306a\U3082\U3093\U304b\Uff1f \U308f\U304c\U307e\U307e\Uff1f \U3046\U307e\U304f\U3084\U308d\U3046\Uff01\U3044\U3053\U3046\Uff01 \U30ae\U30f3\U30ae\U30f3\U597d\U5947\U5fc3\U306e\U76ee\U305f\U3061 \U30af\U30bd\U306e\U547d\U306f\U5982\U4f55\U306b\Uff1f \U884c\U304b\U306a\U304f\U3061\U3083 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U306a \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U3042\U3069\U3051\U306a\U3044\U3000\U305d\U308a\U3083\U306d \U6c7a\U5b9a\U304b\U3089\U306e \U901f\U3055\U306f\U7570\U5e38\U3060\U3057 \U8a00\U308f\U306a\U3044\U3067 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U3060 \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U88cf\U8fd4\U3057\U3067\U3082 \U306a\U3093\U3067\U3082\U3044\U3044\U3088 \U3059\U3050\U6b32\U3057\U304c\U308a\U3060\U306d \U884c\U3063\U3061\U3083\U3046\U306e\Uff1f";
                height = 338;
                html = "&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8y-dHKkp2zU&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
                "provider_name" = YouTube;
                "provider_url" = "https://www.youtube.com/";
                "thumbnail_height" = 360;
                "thumbnail_url" = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/8y-dHKkp2zU/hqdefault.jpg";
                "thumbnail_width" = 480;
                title = "BiSH/BiSH-\U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b- [OFFICIAL VIDEO]";
                type = video;
                url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8y-dHKkp2zU";
                version = "1.0";
                width = 600;
            };
            type = "youtube.com";
        };
        "media_embed" =         {
            content = "&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"//cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8y-dHKkp2zU&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
            height = 338;
            scrolling = 0;
            width = 600;
        };
        "mod_reports" =         (
        );
        name = "t3_3ukrul";
        "num_comments" = 4;
        "num_reports" = "<null>";
        "over_18" = 0;
        permalink = "/r/listentothis/comments/3ukrul/bish_at_night_the_stars_twinkling_rock_indie/";
        "post_hint" = "rich:video";
        preview =         {
            images =             (
                                {
                    id = "-ckcc2kqrPzxZ6Hc78zqqMfheQWZqSww91jcirlOU4Q";
                    resolutions =                     (
                                                {
                            height = 81;
                            url = "https://i.redditmedia.com/nWP7lBZpNof7F-NBhZPCNqSgl7lCA6f6WGXnvjkkMtk.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=108&amp;s=9b6bf9f0327d21eedbcaf69fb80dabb8";
                            width = 108;
                        },
                                                {
                            height = 162;
                            url = "https://i.redditmedia.com/nWP7lBZpNof7F-NBhZPCNqSgl7lCA6f6WGXnvjkkMtk.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=216&amp;s=ebdbaa6fe945dc7ab36cb3a7806c62c2";
                            width = 216;
                        },
                                                {
                            height = 240;
                            url = "https://i.redditmedia.com/nWP7lBZpNof7F-NBhZPCNqSgl7lCA6f6WGXnvjkkMtk.jpg?fit=crop&amp;crop=faces%2Centropy&amp;arh=2&amp;w=320&amp;s=2b85d1579fbebcec2d4aede757d28541";
                            width = 320;
                        }
                    );
                    source =                     {
                        height = 360;
                        url = "https://i.redditmedia.com/nWP7lBZpNof7F-NBhZPCNqSgl7lCA6f6WGXnvjkkMtk.jpg?s=0277bef644bfd78aa432bd7abafba918";
                        width = 480;
                    };
                    variants =                     {
                    };
                }
            );
        };
        quarantine = 0;
        "removal_reason" = "<null>";
        "report_reasons" = "<null>";
        saved = 0;
        score = 41;
        "secure_media" =         {
            oembed =             {
                "author_name" = BiSHTUBE;
                "author_url" = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6UZX3ax9mq-c1P4hh7oDyQ";
                description = "Brand-new idol SHiT http://www.amazon.co.jp/Brand-new-idol-SHiT-BiSH/dp/B00UG99D6C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&amp;qid=1430188312&amp;sr=8-1&amp;keywords=BiSH \U6b4c\U8a5e\U2193 BiSH-\U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b- \U4f5c\U8a5e BiSH\U00d7JxSxK\U00d7\U677e\U9688\U30b1\U30f3\U30bf\U3000\U4f5c\U66f2 \U677e\U9688\U30b1\U30f3\U30bf \U3042\U3042\U5acc\U3044 \U3084\U3081\U306b\U3057\U306a\U3044\Uff1f \U30cf\U30c3\U30bf\U30ea\U3070\U304b\U308a \U5e7e\U5343\U306e\U3053\U3053\U306f\U307e\U308b\U3067 \U30d1\U30e9\U30c0\U30a4\U30b9\Uff1f \U9593\U9055\U3044 \U7b97\U6570\U82e6\U624b\U306a\U5b66\U751f\U305f\U3061\U304c \U3042\U304f\U305b\U304f\U3068 \U96fb\U5353\U305f\U305f\U304f \U4e16\U754c \U30ae\U30f3\U30ae\U30f3\U306b\U62e1\U6563\U306a\U3055\U308c\U305f \U30a2\U30a4\U30c9\U30eb\U306e\U547d\U306f\U5982\U4f55\U306b\Uff1f \U884c\U304b\U306a\U304f\U3061\U3083 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U306a \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U3042\U3069\U3051\U306a\U3044\U3000\U305d\U308a\U3083\U306d \U6c7a\U5b9a\U304b\U3089\U306e \U901f\U3055\U306f\U7570\U5e38\U3060\U3057 \U8a00\U308f\U306a\U3044\U3067 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U3060 \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U88cf\U8fd4\U3057\U3067\U3082 \U306a\U3093\U3067\U3082\U3044\U3044\U3088 \U3059\U3050\U6b32\U3057\U304c\U308a\U3060\U306d \U884c\U3063\U3061\U3083\U3046\U306e\Uff1f \U554f\U984c \U3042\U3063\U3051\U3089\U304b\U3093\U306b \U898b\U3048\U3066\U308b\U306a\U3089\U3070 \U4e71\U5fc3\U3067 \U3072\U3063\U304d\U308a\U306a\U3057\U306b \U523b\U307f\U305f\U3044 \U6b63\U89e3 \U5618\U3064\U304d\U3060\U3089\U3051\U554f\U984c\U3042\U308a\U306e \U30ad\U30c4\U30cd\U3061\U3083\U3093\U305f\U3061\U3082 \U3053\U3053\U306b\U6765\U308c\U3070 \U30d1\U30e9\U30c0\U30a4\U30b9\Uff01 \U30ae\U30f3\U30ae\U30f3\U597d\U5947\U5fc3\U306e\U76ee\U305f\U3061 \U30a2\U30a4\U30c9\U30eb\U306e\U547d\U306f\U5982\U4f55\U306b\Uff1f \U884c\U304b\U306a\U304f\U3061\U3083 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U306a \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U3042\U3069\U3051\U306a\U3044\U3000\U305d\U308a\U3083\U306d \U6c7a\U5b9a\U304b\U3089\U306e \U901f\U3055\U306f\U7570\U5e38\U3060\U3057 \U8a00\U308f\U306a\U3044\U3067 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U3060 \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U88cf\U8fd4\U3057\U3067\U3082 \U306a\U3093\U3067\U3082\U3044\U3044\U3088 \U3059\U3050\U6b32\U3057\U304c\U308a\U3060\U306d \U884c\U3063\U3061\U3083\U3046\U306e\Uff1f \U8ab0\U3067\U3082 \U308f\U3051\U3044\U304b\U305a \U305d\U3093\U306a\U3082\U3093\U304b\Uff1f \U308f\U304c\U307e\U307e\Uff1f \U3046\U307e\U304f\U3084\U308d\U3046\Uff01\U3044\U3053\U3046\Uff01 \U30ae\U30f3\U30ae\U30f3\U597d\U5947\U5fc3\U306e\U76ee\U305f\U3061 \U30af\U30bd\U306e\U547d\U306f\U5982\U4f55\U306b\Uff1f \U884c\U304b\U306a\U304f\U3061\U3083 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U306a \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U3042\U3069\U3051\U306a\U3044\U3000\U305d\U308a\U3083\U306d \U6c7a\U5b9a\U304b\U3089\U306e \U901f\U3055\U306f\U7570\U5e38\U3060\U3057 \U8a00\U308f\U306a\U3044\U3067 \U5316\U3051\U7269\U3060\U3063\U3066\U3000\U6c17\U306b\U3059\U3093\U3060 \U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b keep my face \U88cf\U8fd4\U3057\U3067\U3082 \U306a\U3093\U3067\U3082\U3044\U3044\U3088 \U3059\U3050\U6b32\U3057\U304c\U308a\U3060\U306d \U884c\U3063\U3061\U3083\U3046\U306e\Uff1f";
                height = 338;
                html = "&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8y-dHKkp2zU&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
                "provider_name" = YouTube;
                "provider_url" = "https://www.youtube.com/";
                "thumbnail_height" = 360;
                "thumbnail_url" = "https://i.embed.ly/1/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=b1e305db91cf4aa5a86b732cc9fffceb";
                "thumbnail_width" = 480;
                title = "BiSH/BiSH-\U661f\U304c\U77ac\U304f\U591c\U306b- [OFFICIAL VIDEO]";
                type = video;
                url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8y-dHKkp2zU";
                version = "1.0";
                width = 600;
            };
            type = "youtube.com";
        };
        "secure_media_embed" =         {
            content = "&lt;iframe class=\"embedly-embed\" src=\"https://cdn.embedly.com/widgets/media.html?src=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%3Ffeature%3Doembed&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8y-dHKkp2zU&amp;image=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2F8y-dHKkp2zU%2Fhqdefault.jpg&amp;key=2aa3c4d5f3de4f5b9120b660ad850dc9&amp;type=text%2Fhtml&amp;schema=youtube\" width=\"600\" height=\"338\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;";
            height = 338;
            scrolling = 0;
            width = 600;
        };
        selftext = "";
        "selftext_html" = "<null>";
        stickied = 0;
        subreddit = listentothis;
        "subreddit_id" = "t5_2qxzy";
        "suggested_sort" = "<null>";
        thumbnail = "http://b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/GB0aQLLDIpwIkxXawuVNyfR6RqJG-qJdLR0MS0BJzaA.jpg";
        title = "BiSH -- At night the stars twinkling [rock indie jrock idols] (2015)";
        ups = 41;
        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8y-dHKkp2zU";
        "user_reports" =         (
        );
        visited = 0;
    };
    kind = t3;
}
```

Comment: What's your code? What did you try?

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962562/filtering-nsarray-of-dictionaries-in-swift)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    let dict_data : NSMutableDictionary = tableData[self.selectedRow] as! NSMutableDictionary

    var data_song = String(stringInterpolationSegment: dict_data["data"]!["title"] as! String)
```

I was able to create an NSMutableDictionary and then access the attributes of the dictionary.